# CDI session scoped bean is created only one time also if the user access from two different browser

Tags: spring, session, jsf, cdi

i have a strange behaviour i'm seeing that if the user access to session bean from two different browser, the istance of session bean is the same.  In my opinion this is an unespected behaviour.
Someone have solved the same problem?
I'm using Jsf 2.0, Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate and like WebServer Glassfish.
Thank you in advance.

**Update**

```
import model.entity.Utente;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
```

this is how i declare CDI session bean

Comment: Do you really use CDI together with Spring?

Comment: mmm, how i can see if Spring is using real CDI binding?

Comment: now i'm debugging and the bean is created also if there isn't beans.xml so i think that that bean isn't CDI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the bean is managed by Spring not by CDI. (If you want to use CDI with Spring you need to do a lot of work, only using `javax.inject.Named` is not enougth.)

Spring knows `javax.inject.Named` but not `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`. To make a Spring Bean Session scoped, you need `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("session")`.

@see also: [Spring Reference Chapter 3.5.4 Request, session, and global session scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-scopes-other)

Comment: OK, it's right. I have already canghed the code but now i have a null pointer excpetion. I'm trying to inject Session Bean in my Custom Login Filter.. but i thik that the login filter is created before a user session start.I'm using Spring security too. Have you some ideas?

Comment: If you use Spring Session Beans, you need to add a special filter for that and may some additional configuration. But I don't know the name at the moment.